# How do I enforce, that the sum of a weight parameter equals 1, grouped by part of the key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, normalization

I have two tables in my setup. One with sales persons and there income. Each sales person only know their total income. For this particular income period, they are asked to give an estimate of their income on either private, small business or large business customers. This information is entered in the second table.

```
Income
=================
SalesPerson
Income

Distribution
=============================
SalesPerson
CustomerType
Weight
```

Now, my query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  Income.SalesPerson,
  Distribution.CustomerType,
  Income.Income * Distribution.Weight as DistributedIncome
FROM
  Income INNER JOIN Distribution ON
    Income.SalesPerson = Distribution.SalesPerson
```

How would I enforce, that the `SUM(Weight)` = 1 for each `SalesPerson` in `Distribution`?

Answer (score 1):

Normalize by the sum, according to the same criteria.

```
SELECT
  Income.SalesPerson,
  Distribution.CustomerType,
  Income.Income * Distribution.Weight/(
    select sum(d.weight)
    from distribution d
    inner join income i on i.salesperson = d.salesperson
  )
  as DistributedIncome
FROM
  Income INNER JOIN Distribution ON
    Income.SalesPerson = Distribution.SalesPerson
```

If somehow want to select unmodified weights that sum to 1 then I believe you've got a case of the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and you are probably not going to be able to solve this with an SQL query.

Comment: Well, yes, I thought of that. However, it's not very pretty, and in my actual problem, it'll be alot more complicated. I know it solves the problem, but it doesn't enforce the sum of the weights to be 1, for which I have a need for other reasons. Oh yes, another thing: If a user only enters one customer type and enters 0 in weight, I would get divison by zero.

Comment: Yes it does - it's just a [weighted mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_mean).

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't express my point. I know the calculation will be correct (as if the SUM(Weight) equals 1), but I do not only want the result to be correct. I want the actual SUM(Weight) to be 1.